# Raspberry Pi 3 Polyfuse rating?

Tags: pi-3

Does anybody know the model used. Or have done tests to determine at what current load the polyfuse starts kicking in?

I want to work out how much current I can draw via the GPIO power pins.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended power supply is 5.1 volts and 2.5 amps for the Pi3.  One assumes the polyfuse must have been increased to allow 2.5 amps to flow.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/#raspberry-pi-3-on-sale

Comment: There is now a Schematic for the Pi3 on the Foundation website which shows the fuse is MF-MSMF250/X